# Codeigniter- make an access denied if the user tried to enter a pass that belong to another user level

Tags: codeigniter, security, authentication

I have in controller Admin.php, Members.php, Atendementos.php and same in views added this folders, and there is script to redirect to each one depend on the user level.

What I need to make a secure path that if user is not an admin and tried to go to app/admin/access for example have to give him a massage that he can't access this page. how can i do that ? thank you.

Comment: Hi @KirkBeard i edited the post .. thank you,

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution
application/libraries/My_auth.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class Auth{
    protected   $CI;

    public      $sess_array         = array();

    public function __construct(){
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

    public function login_user( $usr = '', $psw = '', $where = NULL ){

        $result = $this->CI->db->get_where('user', array($where => $usr, 'password' => $psw))->row();

        return ($result) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    }

    public function create_session( $usr = '', $psw = '', $where = NULL ){

        $result     = $this->CI->db->get_where('user', array($where => $usr, 'password' => $psw))->row();

        $language   = $this->CI->session->userdata('language');

        $this->CI->session->set_userdata('id', $result->id);
        $this->CI->session->set_userdata('email', $usr);
        $this->CI->session->set_userdata('username', $result->username);
        $this->CI->session->set_userdata('level', $result->level);
        $this->CI->session->set_userdata('language', $language);

        $cookie     = array(
                            'name'   => 'elddenmedio_session',
                            'value'  => '57',
                            'expire' => '86500',
                            'domain' => '.' . base_url(),
                            'path'   => '/',
                            'prefix' => '',
                            'secure' => TRUE
                        );

        $this->CI->input->set_cookie($cookie);
    }

    //
    public function has_permission( $level = '' ){
        if($this->get_level() != $level){
            redirect(base_url(), 'refresh');
        }
    }

    public function get_level(){
        return ( empty($this->CI->session->userdata('level'))) ? LEVEL_PUBLIC : $this->CI->session->userdata('level');
    }

    //more methos
}
```

controller application/noram_user.php

```
class Normal_user extends CI_Controller{
    var $user_id;

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->auth->has_permission('normal_user');

        $this->user_id                          = $this->session->userdata('id');
    }
}
```

application/admin.php

```
class Normal_user extends CI_Controller{
    var $user_id;

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->auth->has_permission('admin');

        $this->user_id                          = $this->session->userdata('id');
    }
}
```